# Why is .add_reaction not working with unicode emojis?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I canot seem to get this single line of code to output anything except `BAD REQUEST Unknown Emoji`

```py
await dBot.add_reaction(message,"\\U00000031")
```

I cannot find any reason online why this shouldnt work. What wonderful noob mistake am I making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you're using isn't an escaped Unicode character, but an escaped backslash character followed by eight digit characters. You probably want only one backslash in the literal, which will let Python parse the literal into a single character as it seems you intend. I'm still not sure that will do what you expect though, since `"\U00000031"` is the character `'1'`, not an emoji.

From your comment below, it sounds like the emoji you actually want is composed of two Unicode codepoints. The first is just the normal `'1'` character I discussed above, which you don't need any escapes to write. The second character is `U+20E3` ('COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP'), which can be written in a Python literal as `'\u20E3'` or `'\U000020E3'`. This puts a keyboard key image around whatever the previous character was, so the sequence `"1\u20e3"` will render as 1⃣ (which my browser doesn't handle too well, but yours might). I don't know for sure, but I'd be fairly confident that discord would accept that, if it support the `1` key emoji you're looking for at all (which I expect it does).

Comment: Hi, thanks. just to clear up a few things, i tried the unicode in various formats "\U00000031" "U00000031" "U+0031" and various other attempts and nothing. also, according to
http://www.fileformat.info/info/emoji/list.htm
thats a legit emoji number

Comment: That link suggests that the emoji (1 in a keycap) is composed of two unicode characters. The first is just a normal `1` digit (which you can write as just `"1"` in Python rather than `"\U00000031"`), followed by `U+20E3`, which is a combining character that turns whatever precedes it into an image of a key from a keyboard. So try `"1\u20E3"`.

Comment: do you think you'd be able to post that as an answer please @Blckknght ? so i can close this question, thanks again